# In installing orange imageanalytics

Tags: python, visual-c++, anaconda, orange

In installing ImageAnalytics in orange3 software i am getting these error,

```
Collecting Orange3-ImageAnalytics
  Downloading Orange3-ImageAnalytics-0.1.13.tar.gz (2.3MB)
Requirement already satisfied: Orange3>=3.3.5 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Collecting Pillow>=4.2.1 (from Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
  Downloading Pillow-5.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (1.6MB)
Collecting cachecontrol (from Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
  Downloading CacheControl-0.12.3.tar.gz
Collecting hyper>=0.7.0 (from Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
  Downloading hyper-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (269kB)
Collecting lap==0.3.0 (from Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
  Downloading lap-0.3.0.tar.gz (1.5MB)
Collecting lockfile (from Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
  Downloading lockfile-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.0 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: keyrings.alt in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: dill in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.9.4 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.3 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: CommonMark>=0.5.5 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: bottleneck>=1.0.0 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.16.1 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: serverfiles in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: pyqtgraph>=0.10.0 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.18.1 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: AnyQt>=0.0.8 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd>=0.9.2 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: keyring in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet>=3.0.2 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Collecting msgpack-python (from cachecontrol->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
  Downloading msgpack-python-0.4.8.tar.gz (113kB)
Collecting h2<3.0,>=2.4 (from hyper>=0.7.0->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
  Downloading h2-2.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
Collecting hyperframe<4.0,>=3.2 (from hyper>=0.7.0->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
  Downloading hyperframe-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from requests->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from requests->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from requests->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from keyrings.alt->Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: pyreadline>=1.7.1 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from dill->Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from CommonMark>=0.5.5->Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\certainty2\appdata\local\orange\lib\site-packages (from keyring->Orange3>=3.3.5->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
Collecting hpack<4,>=2.2 (from h2<3.0,>=2.4->hyper>=0.7.0->Orange3-ImageAnalytics)
  Downloading hpack-3.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: Orange3-ImageAnalytics, cachecontrol, lap, msgpack-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Orange3-ImageAnalytics: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Orange3-ImageAnalytics: finished with status 'done'
  Running setup.py clean for Orange3-ImageAnalytics
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cachecontrol: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cachecontrol: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Certainty2\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\2b\fd\77\677be47e3d4f83d2e8d07299f61697aa508e6f8b5d08d94050
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lap: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lap: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Certainty2\AppData\Local\Orange\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\CERTAI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-n42rgcz0\\lap\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\CERTAI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpr3xg7jbjpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  Partial import of lap during the build process.
  Generating cython files
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building extension "lap._lapjv" sources
  building data_files sources
  build_src: building npy-pkg config files
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lap
  copying lap\lapmod.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lap
  copying lap\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lap
  running build_ext
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
  customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
  building 'lap._lapjv' extension
  compiling C sources
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lap
  Running setup.py clean for lap
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for msgpack-python: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for msgpack-python: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Certainty2\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\2c\e7\e7\9031652a69d594665c5ca25e41d0fb3faa024e730b590e4402
Successfully built cachecontrol msgpack-python
Failed to build Orange3-ImageAnalytics lap
Installing collected packages: Pillow, msgpack-python, cachecontrol, hyperframe, hpack, h2, hyper, lap, lockfile, Orange3-ImageAnalytics
  Running setup.py install for lap: started
    Running setup.py install for lap: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Certainty2\AppData\Local\Orange\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\CERTAI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-n42rgcz0\\lap\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\CERTAI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-bn2gvmhk-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Partial import of lap during the build process.
    Generating cython files
    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building extension "lap._lapjv" sources
    building data_files sources
    build_src: building npy-pkg config files
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lap
    copying lap\lapmod.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lap
    copying lap\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lap
    running build_ext
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
    customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
    building 'lap._lapjv' extension
    compiling C sources
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\Certainty2\AppData\Local\Orange\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\CERTAI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-n42rgcz0\\lap\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\CERTAI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-bn2gvmhk-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\CERTAI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-n42rgcz0\lap\
```

I already have Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools . but same error happens . and i had already tried previous these solutions but nothing worked ,

https://github.com/biolab/orange3-imageanalytics/pull/82

https://github.com/biolab/orange3-imageanalytics/issues/80

Comment: The bug is now fixed, Orange3 Image Analytics should now work without installing Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools.  
Fix is already included in the latest release. 
https://github.com/biolab/orange3-imageanalytics/pull/84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to install microsoft build tools with latest versions say 2015 and 2017 . Then if problem remains same then you can go towards fix i had given here [FixOrangeImageAnalysis](https://github.com/shubhamsharmacs/Orangeimageanalysisbugsolve/blob/master/README.md) . 
and you must download zip file i had shared there . and put all into your Orange/Lib/site-packages folder .
All files whose names startes with any of following must be replaced

1. h
2. cache
3. lap
4. lock
5. msg
6. pill
7. orange
8. pillow
9. image
10. imageanalytics.pth

I guess [FixOrangeImageAnalysis](https://github.com/shubhamsharmacs/Orangeimageanalysisbugsolve/blob/master/README.md) should solve your issue